# Need to make git think that every file in the repository has changed

Tags: git

In order to test an upgrade process I need to `git reset --hard $sha` and then `git push -f` to the development git repository in a dev/test/prod setup.  The only way I can get this older code to the test and prod repositories is by clicking a button that does a `git pull` from dev. So I'm looking for the most benign way to make git think that every file in the repository has changed. I need a repeatable way of doing this has I will have to push old code up to the test and prod repositories multiple times.

I've thought of appending a new line to every file. This would have to be done with care because there are image files and some directories that should be skipped.

Maybe there is some way of touching files to update timestamps.  I tried changing the modification time on a file, but that did not result in `git status` detecting a change.

I bet there is some git way to achieve what I want.  I know I'm kind of working against git here, but I don't see another way.  The instance of the application I'm working on has been cloned for test purposes so I'm comfortable with doing non-standard things in the repository.

Comment: Did this question violate some SO best practice?  Is that why I got down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only file metadata that is tracked by git is the executable flag. So you could toggle this on all files to get all files changed. Other than that I don't think you have a chance. Timestamps are no content and git is a content change tracker.